# Music player at the bottom page in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new on react-native and need some help to understand it.

I want to achieve a music player that is placed at the bottom *(above @react-navigation/bottom-tabs)*, and a have a few questions about:

- how to create a control that remains always at the bottom, and above the bottoms-tab that keep its state ?
- when the user navigates through the menu the music player should not stop, so the player should remains the same along the whole experience. how do I achieve this ?

[image]